# Whats the reason why these 2 questions got closed?

Tags: discussion

Both questions come to moderation:

[Joomla Custom-Component Select Field with Editor](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/22787/joomla-custom-component-select-field-with-editor)

[Subform inside modal](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/21589/subform-inside-modal)

both get closed by [mickmackusa](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/users/12352/mickmackusa) and [lodder](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/users/168/lodder)

But I can't see why it got closed because they are valid for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Subform inside modal:

The questions I would have asked the OP:

- Have you researched sub form fields and what the posibilities are?
- Have you tried to write any code yourself so far? And if so, can you share it?
- What do you mean by "**shorten the parameters list**"?

Based on this, I voted to close the question as too broad.

---

#### Joomla Custom-Component Select Field with Editor

This question is simply too broad and shows no effort whatsoever. When I initially saw it and re-look at the question now, the first thing that sprung to mind was "please do my work for me".

If you look at the question, you'll see no comments or answers at all.

Ask yourself why.

I'd say it's too broad for people to event attempt to start.

---

I see that you've reopened them and respect that, but it's a slim chance it will get any further attention. Will just have to wait and see I suppose.

Comment: Hmm the close reason confused me because because it was offtopic, but maybe that was selected because no other reason fits?
I will give some short answers to the questions to point into the direction I would not see a reason to do a complete component development ;-)

Comment: @HaraldLeithner - It was mickmackusa that voted to close both as off-topic. I'll normally go with the community reason for voting to close

Comment: No problem with this, just wanted to ask and because SE shows me the flag too.

Answer (score 1):

I voted to close both questions as Off-Topic because there were lists of task requirements and seemingly no attempt to self-solve.  The first is very Broad and seeks multiple solutions.  The second is less Broad, but more vague as there is no context.

Quote that I was relying on when deciding my vote justification:

> Generally questions that ask for coding a solution must present some effort and that the user is in place to understand what the code is about.

---

By not closing these types of questions, users will assume that these types of questions are on-topic; this leads to more Broad / no effort / "here are my list of requirements" questions in the future.  Upvoting these questions preserves the page even after closing (cannot be Roomba'ed). "Answering" these types of questions with a hint / general guidance may feel like you are helping but future researchers are probably hungry for something more substantial.

Let's face facts, the user base here has a higher saturation of non-developers than Stackoverflow.  This generally means that the questions need a bit more handling / preparation to expose the technical nature of what is being asked.  AND answers really need to spell out what needs to be done -- often transcending Joomla-speak and explaining where each adjustment should be made and in which specific file and why.

When a volunteer wants to help, but a question is Too Broad, Off-topic, missing vital details, shows no effort, or has no context, then it is better to temporarily close and/or comment to request improvement versus providing a "guess" or vague/general suggestions as answers.  (This is not an attack on Harald's posts, but rather my blanket philosophical stance.)

Although I am super new to Joomla, I only mean to be helpful to this community.  Please factor that in when you are trying to determine the "tone" of my text.